# Sum(XY) in terms of Xbar and Ybar

Tags: mean, sum

If $x$ and $y$ are two series, is there any relation between $\sum{(x,y)}$ that can be expressed in terms of mean of these two. Specifically, I want to know if any sort of relation exists between $\sum(x,y)$ and $\sum{(\bar{x}, \bar{y})}$.

Comment: I assume $\sum ( x,y) = (\sum x,\sum y )$. Is there any assumptions? like x and y are independent and elements in x or y are i.i.d.?

Comment: yes x and y are independent and both of the series has positive numbers.  I know \sum{x,y} != \sum{x}.\sum{y}. Want to know if there is any other relation.

Comment: @nth what exactly do you denote by (x,y)?

Comment: Please explain your notation. In comments you appear to have agreed that $\sum(x,y)$ means $(\sum_i x_i, \sum_i y_i)$, but if that's the case it's trivially true that $\sum (\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ equals $\sum(x,y)$: I therefore suspect you have something else in mind.

Answer (score 1):

There's a relation between mean product and covariance: `E[XY] = Cov[X,Y] + E[X]E[Y]`.
Unless you have a reason to believe the covariance is zero, there is no way to express the mean product in terms of means of the variables alone.